# WSO2 ESB4.0.3 can not use XQUery

Tags: wso2, xquery, wso2-esb

In ESB4.0.0,I can use XQuery like this:

```
xquery key="conf:/closeUserRequest_xq" variable 
xmlns:ns="http://service.jscn.coship.com/"   
xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
name="closeUser1" 
expression="//p:closeUser/userId" type="DOCUMENT"/>xquery
```

But when I upgrade to ESB4.0.3, use this error like:

```
[2012-04-21 11:31:53,342] ERROR - XQueryMediator Unable to execute the query
java.lang.NullPointerException at 
org.wso2.carbon.mediation.registry.WSO2Registry.lookup(WSO2Registry.java:177) at 
org.apache.synapse.registry.AbstractRegistry.getResource(AbstractRegistry.java:63) at 
org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration.getEntry(SynapseConfiguration.java:693)at 
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext.getEntry(Axis2MessageContext.java:194)at 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.xquery.XQueryMediator.performQuery(XQueryMediator.java:233)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is your Xquery script  available in the registry? Check whether the registry path is right..

Comment: I do not kown whether available. But the same registry can work in ESB4.0.0.  <xquery xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" key="conf:/messageTransformerReq_xq" />. Can you tell me what is the right registry path in 4.0.3?

Comment: Go to your Registrybrowser and check at the configuration registry whether the script is available or not

Comment: Ratha, thank you. I think the registry path is right. I added a xslt in the same path. It can work. The XQuery can also work in 4.0.0. I do not know why can not use in 4.0.3. My XQuery is :declare function xf:closeUserRequest($message1 as node()) as element() {let $message := $message1 
return <message><body><xmlRequest><cycleIndex>{$message/p:cycleIndex/text()}</cycleIndex></xmlRequest></body></message>};
declare variable $message1 as node() external;xf:closeUserRequest($message1)

Comment: I have solved this problem. In 4.0.3, you must set "Media type" value "XQuery"